# A word to describe our lack of concern with the world as children

Tags: single-word-requests

A word to describe our inability to see beyond ourselves, something to do with our innocence that doesn't allow us to see it.

Here is what I am writing:

> You may have of heard of the saying, “I guess that’s when the reality really hit me.”, but you never truly understand this until you come to say it for yourself. We have come so far into our complacency in this society as to believe that we live in a “colorblind” society. I take this back to our ____ minds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Innocence*** is a concept often accociated to children:

***[Innocent​](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/innocent)***:

> - having no knowledge of the unpleasant and evil things in life.

- I take this back to our innocent minds.

also:

***[Ingenuous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ingenuous)***  or ***candid, sencere***:

> - free from reserve, restraint, or dissimulation.

Dictionary.com

Answer (score 2):

You should consider ***naive*** which implies *innocent* but more importantly also *lacking in experience or knowledge* (to go with the context of “I guess that’s when the reality really hit me.”)

> I take this back to our ***naive*** minds...

M-W:

> **[naive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naive)**
>   *adjective*
>
> Simple Definition
>   : having or showing a lack of experience or
>   knowledge : innocent or simple
>
> Full Definition:
>   **2**
>   **a** :  deficient in worldly wisdom or informed judgment
>
> a naive belief that all people are good
>   I was young and naive at the
>   time, and I didn't think anything bad could happen to me.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't entirely fit your example sentence,and it isn't a single word but the term **[Infant Solipsism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism#Infant_solipsism)** seems to cover the concept you describe.

> **Infant solipsism**
>
> Some developmental psychologists believe that infants are [**solipsist**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/solipsism), and that eventually children infer that others have experiences much like theirs and reject solipsism (see  Infant cognitive development).

Answer (score 0):

'[Oblivious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oblivious)' would be the right word. It means "not conscious of something, especially what is happening around you".

But the word 'carefree' can also be used to project a more positive meaning.

Comment: Please don't just link. Please quote (and link). See the other answers.

Answer (score -3):

carefree;insouciant;happy go lucky.
She remembered carefree summers at the beach.
with insouciant, the definition goes like pretty much these other words. 
A happy-go-lucky girl. Licensed from iStockPhoto. adjective. The definitionof happy-go-lucky is someone who is generally easygoing and carefree. An easygoing kid who takes things as they come is an example of someone who would be described as happy-go-lucky.

Comment: Please see the other answers, and how they justify the words they suggest. **Why** are these words suitable?

Comment: well guess i can't justify myself in this case. I'm writing these three for I remembered them used in a context befitting, at least seems so, to what the  original poster is asking.  lesson learned though: will provide compelling evidence next time.